# Hibernate Criteria query doesnt query the many in one to many

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to create a one to many query. the join seems to be working because the set gets populated but when i add a query to the set it doesn't seem to do anything

Here is one class:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent")
    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }
```

Here is the other

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
    public Parent getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }
```

and here is the not working query

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Parent.class,"p")
               .setFetchMode("p.children", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .createAlias("p.children", "c")
               .add(Restrictions.like("p.name", "%" + nameQuery + "%").ignoreCase())
               .add(Restrictions.eq("c.gender", "boy"));
```

and this query gets me all my parents by name correnctly and their all children, but i only want the boy children and yet it gives me all the girls too. anyone see what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching),

```
    Join fetching: Hibernate retrieves the associated instance or collection 
in the same SELECT, using an OUTER JOIN.
```

In an outer join, you will get all the records in both the tables irrespective of the join condition, so change your fetching strategy to `SELECT` and it should fetch only the results matching the restriction. Also I'd recommend to enable batch fetching if you're not doing that already.

Comment: what about FetchMode.EAGER ?

Comment: lol i just gave up and reverted back to HQL which worked fine